# how to disable keyboard hotkey in java swing

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

i want to disable keyboard hotkey such as `alt` `ctrl` `alt + f4` `ctrl + alt + dlt` in my netbeans project so that no one can open anything while my application is on

Comment: You can't (and shouldn't) disable `ctrl-alt-del`, unless you're essentially disabling the keyboard itself. See http://superuser.com/questions/142176/how-can-i-disable-the-ctrl-alt-del-key-combination-completely-on-xp-vista-7

Comment: i just want that the user cannot close or skip to the software in any kind not even through these hotkeys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, disabling keys is a difficult thing, but i think you problem can be resolved another way:

```
yourFrameOrWindow.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

This will make your application always on the screen, if its full screen, then your problem is solved, but this will not disable ctrl+alt+del, or other attempts to close your application.

And for some combinations of keys, I think you can map them in a method onKeyPress an then let it empty, like this:

```
void onKeyPress(int keyCode){
    if(keyCode == 43){
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

but i think have a specific listener for combinations of keys.

Comment: can you tell me what is 43 here

Comment: the code of the key that you want, each key has a code. See come constants here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html and I think the ASCII table will do the job too https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Answer (score 3):

You are asking for a way *within* Netbeans to disable global keyboard hotkeys for Windows. This simply isn't possible, as both of your key combinations are registered and intercepted at the kernel level way before Netbeans or any other Windows application even notices them.

There are ways to disable these kinds of hotkeys within Windows, but this can't be done programmatically with Java. Instead try Googling "Disable hotkeys Windows X" or "Disable ctrl alt del Windows X.

An answer on SuperUser suggests a possible registry fix for disabling ctrl+alt+del on Windows 7. The suggested registry edit is:

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\taskmgr.exe]`

`"Debugger"="Hotkey Disabled"`

There are other ways of disabling certain hotkeys depending on what version of Windows you are running and what kind of access you have to the computer. Without admin rights, any solution will be difficult.

This could also be done problematically using a lower level language such as C++ or even C#, but I don't think any of the Java libraries can intercept and **block** low level keyboard events.

Comment: my users are anonymous i cannot go to their computer and disable it , i want that when they open my software they cannot close or do anything until the application closes

Comment: @sahib - Honestly, that sounds like great behavior for a virus, but not for an application. Unless you're writing a virus, you need to rethink your approach here.

Comment: @chris - just think as if it is a software for atm and if a user can skip through the software don't you it would be very harmfull

Comment: @Chris This behavior could be useful in, say, a school lab setting where you don't want students to be able to Google the answer to a computer science test. In which case the issue would be application independent (i.e. group policy); but I can't think of a scenario where you wouldn't have access to the computer in question.

Comment: If it's software for an ATM or for a computer science lab, then you should have access to the OS/registry and/or hardware. The point was that it's not done at the application level (as you alluded to in your answer), but at the underlying level which will affect *all* applications running on that system.

Comment: @chris i dont want to change in registry or in behavior i just want to disable it only in my application for eg. there are some websites on which you click right button in your mouse then the option are completely different from what it should in normal case but that doesn't mean website has changed the behavior of your mouse completely. its just for that website

Comment: Reread Brian's answer - _This simply isn't possible_. I don't think it gets any clearer than that.  Changing right click menus on a webpage is very different than changing what ctrl-alt-del does.