# Disable some PC keyboard keys using JNA

Tags: java, keyboard-shortcuts, jna, hotkeys

I'm working on a software project using Java. I'm also using JavaFX for it's GUI. When this software is run on a PC, it should lock the screen of the PC until a valid pin is entered.

I want some keyboard keys such as the control, alternate and windows key to be disabled when the software is run.

How can I do this using JNA?

Comment: What do you mean by "disable"?  Can you explain what you're trying to do? Your mention of the "Windows key" implies that this is Windows, but which version(s)?

Comment: From WinXP to Win10

Comment: You didn't answer the most important part of my question: What do you mean by "disable"? What effect are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `KeyEvent` to detect whether the target key pressed.

if pressed, do nothing.

and it just similar to `disable`

more detail [how to disable keyboard hotkey in java swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34815721/how-to-disable-keyboard-hotkey-in-java-swing)

---

in this page [is it is possible to disable the windows keys using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486167/is-it-is-possible-to-disable-the-windows-keys-using-java)

you can detect key action via JNA interface, but key still work.

Comment: I tried using the [KeyHook Java class](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7793900/4338203) but I get this error: incompatible types: Pointer cannot be converted to LPARAM at this line of code: return lib.CallNextHookEx(hhk, nCode, wParam, info.getPointer());

Comment: @InyavicSage instead of writing `info.getPointer()`, you can write `new LPARAM(info.getPointer().getLong(0))`, which will reslove the error

Answer (score 0):

You cannot lock the Windows desktop without integrating with the operating system's logon process, which is called *Winlogon*.

In Windows Vista and newer, you could make your PIN process a [Winlogon Credential Provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb648647(v=vs.85).aspx). In Windows XP, you would need to add a [Winlogon GINA hook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380543(v=vs.85).aspx).

Note that it is impossible to block access to all OS user interface elements without the help of the operating system. If nothing else, the user will always be able to use Ctrl-Alt-Del, which is handled directly by the kernel and cannot be intercepted by userland applications.

Comment: I don't wish to block Ctrl-Alt-Del